# how do i give each fragment its own view rather then 1 view different number?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

im using android studio, ive created a project using navigation drawer with fragments,

as you may/may not know it gives default code to show 1 view with the fragment page number for each page u click.

my problem or rather query is how do i give each fragment its own view.

i want to create 3 possibly 4 layout.xml files but want each of the options in the drawer to open its own xml.

i hope this makes sense and here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);

        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DEDBA7")));


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }



        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

Now im guessing this section is the code that places the number in each fragment, but i want to get rid of the number and have a different view for each item i click.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either create different fragments for each and then select the correct fragment you want in onNavigationDrawerItemSelected.

Or you need to pass a meaningful argument to PlaceHolder fragment that will allow you to pick the correct layout and inflate it, in onCreateView.

Comment: Have you looked any of the Fragment tutorials on the Android developer site? If not I would start there. All this is doing is switching out the fragment used based on the item selected in the list. So the creating and using fragments part is the same as any other setup in an application.

Comment: yes i looked on there and started a new app following that guide, but now im stuck once more lol,

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353995/cannot-resolve-method-getsystemservice-and-getcountervisability-nav-drawer

Comment: info is on the link, im sure this is all basic knowledge but im trying to learn android/java programming. practical learning is easiest hence why i just dive in lol