# "cannot resolve method getSystemService and getCounterVisability nav drawer

Tags: android, methods, slidingmenu

im followinf this guide [Sliding Menu using Navdrawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

everything was going well until i got errors on getSystemService and getCounterVisability lines in android studio,

my adapter class is as follows package com.jembe.locals.adapter;

```
import com.jembe.locals.R;
import com.jembe.locals.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
/**
 * Created by mine on 12/03/14.
 */
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
     if (convertView == null) {
         LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                 context.getSytemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
     }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Can anyone give me pointers as to what the problem is?

for info purposes i using android studio, all sdks and support classes installed through sdk manager

> Gradle tasks [:locals:assembleDebug] Execution failed for task
>   ':locals:compileDebugJava'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. C:\Users\mine\AndroidStudioProjects\LocalsAware\locals\src\main\java\com\jembe\locals\adapter\NavDrawerListAdapter.java
> >     error: cannot find symbol method getSytemService(String) error: cannot
> >     find symbol method getCounterVisibility()

also i have my adapter class posted and my mainactivity class.

```
package com.jembe.locals;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] mTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);




        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.drawer_layout, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

this is my navDrawerItem.java

```
package com.jembe.locals.model;

/**
 * Created by mine on 12/03/14.
 */
public class NavDrawerItem {

    private String title;
    private int icon;
    private String count = "0";
    // boolean to set visbility of the counter
    private boolean isCounterVisble = false;

    public NavDrawerItem(){}


    public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon){
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public NavDrawerItem(String title,int icon,boolean isCounterVisble){
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.isCounterVisble = isCounterVisble;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public int getIcon(){
        return this.icon;
    }

    public String getCount(){
        return this.count;
    }

    public boolean getCouterVisibility(){
        return this.isCounterVisble;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setCounterVisble(boolean isCounterVisble) {
        this.isCounterVisble = isCounterVisble;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error, or at least the error messages. Can you paste the code for NavDrawerItem? 

Also you can just call ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater(); to get the layout inflater. Assuming your adapter is being called from an activity.

Comment: yup 2 secs will try get them for u ;)

Comment: Where is the code where you are creating the adapter? Also you may want to look at your NavDrawerItem class and make sure that method exists.

Comment: sorry. ive uodated the question. had to rush about and my head was hurting looking at code since 8am this morning lol

Comment: I would check that when your are calling your NavDrawerListAdapter you're passing in an actual context. Note that if you're doing that from your fragment you need to call getActivity() you can't use this. Even though it might compile. 

As for the 2nd error I'm not sure you're class looks ok. You may want to step through with the debugger and see what you're getting back at that step. If your accessing the ArrayList directly it shouldn't be a problem. But for instance if you use the adapter get method you'll need to case it since it will return object.

Comment: Also android studio should give you some tips on what's going on, and how to fix. Be sure to check the tool tips for those two lines.

Comment: thankyou very much for your help, i decided not to use android studio, exported it to eclipse and all was fine, had to change a couple of lines but all works now so i can ow get on with the rest of my app. thanks very much again for your help.